# Scheduled test class (Add test methods to your test class.)

Tags: unit-test

I wrote my first Schedulable class in SF.

```
    global class Atualizar_Aging_OS implements Schedulable {

    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) { 

        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '___ [cls Atualizar_Aging_OS - execute()] - Inicio... ');

        String query = 'SELECT Id ' +
                            ', StartDate ' +
                            ', EndDate ' +
                            ', Aging__c ' + 
                            'FROM WorkOrder ';

        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '___ [cls Atualizar_Aging_OS - execute()] - query: '+query);

        Atualizar_Aging_OS_Batch batch = new Atualizar_Aging_OS_Batch(query);
        Database.executeBatch(batch, 200); 

    } // Fim execute

}
```

I've searched for a test class and I'm getting the message:
**Add test methods to your test class.**

```
@isTest
public class Teste_Atualizar_Aging_OS {

    //Método para testar o agendamento do Aging
    public static void testschedule() {

        Test.StartTest();
        Atualizar_Aging_OS sh1 = new Atualizar_Aging_OS();      
        String sch = '0 37 11 * * ?';
        system.schedule('Test check', sch, sh1);
        Test.stopTest();

    }     
}
```

Sorry, I'm a begginer in programming. What kind of method should I create to test this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use testMethod modifier for your method in test class to make it a test method.

```
@isTest
public class Teste_Atualizar_Aging_OS {

    //Método para testar o agendamento do Aging
    public static testMethod  void testschedule() {

        Test.StartTest();
        Atualizar_Aging_OS sh1 = new Atualizar_Aging_OS();      
        String sch = '0 37 11 * * ?';
        system.schedule('Test check', sch, sh1);
        Test.stopTest();

    }     
}
```

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods